# System UI crashes randomly

Tags: android-11, crash-reports

System UI crashes about 2 to 3 times a week. After looking at a few crash logs, it is the same every time. This information is generated from the Crash Log View application. - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arumcomm.crashlogviewer

```
Process: com.android.systemui
PID: 1487
UID: 10172
Flags: 0x30c8be0d
Package: com.android.systemui v30 (11)
Foreground: No
Process-Runtime: 1463145
Build: T-Mobile/Sprout/Sprout:11/RP1A.200720.011/SW_S98115AA1_V060:user/release-keys

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.android.systemui.qs.external.TileLifecycleManager@901e525
    at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1775)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1874)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:792)
    at com.android.systemui.qs.external.TileLifecycleManager.setBindService(TileLifecycleManager.java:203)
    at com.android.systemui.qs.external.TileServiceManager.unbindService(TileServiceManager.java:209)
    at com.android.systemui.qs.external.TileServiceManager.setBindAllowed(TileServiceManager.java:176)
    at com.android.systemui.qs.external.TileServices.recalculateBindAllowance(TileServices.java:151)
    at com.android.systemui.qs.external.TileServiceManager$2.run(TileServiceManager.java:258)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

I don't have enough Android knowledge to have any theories, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Factory reset? Are you running a custom ROM???